# Visibilidade de e-mail e senha após submit (Facebook)

Tags: php, segurança, criptografia, certificado-digital, ssl

Estou com uma duvida em relação à senhas. Resolvi fazer uma "experiência" para ver a segurança dos dados enviados por formulários, e mesmo usando protocolo de segurança notei que é possível literalmente **LER e VER** a senha enviada.

O navegador envia tudo de forma limpa. Ignorante que sou com o tema segurança, sempre pensei que o navegador enviasse os dados 'obfuscados' ou criptografia e reversão usando **SSL**.

**Usei o Facebook para testar**, em outras palavras, é possível encontrar o login e a senha de acesso de uma conta que esteja aberta em uma maquina. Dei um printscreen no console para ilustrar os dados encontrados.

> <sup>Naturalmente ocultei alguns campos e alterei a senha</sup>
>   <sub>Mas a senha exibida no console é a mesma da minha conta no Facebook</sub>

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### <sub>Pergunta</sub>

- O que é possível fazer para se evitar esse tipo de coisa?
- O protocolo de segurança não resolve esse tipo de situação?

Comment: como exatamente fez o teste?

Comment: @DanielOmine, fiz o login normal e fui redirecionado para a pagina principal, e lá no console estava a url `POST login.php[...]`, somente isso.

Comment: rsrs.. imaginei isso. Mas isso é normal. rsrs.. O que vc está vendo é os dados que o navegador já recebeu e decodificou.

Comment: Mesmo assim, se recebeu e enviou, não deveria destruir para evitar essa exibição? É até mais fácil que instalar um `keylogger` no PC da namorada rsrsrs. Fora a brincadeira, qualquer um pode ter acesso às informações enviadas.

Comment: ?? mas se vc printar na tela vai aparecer mesmo.. rsrsrs.. Aliás, por quê está aparecendo no console.log? Só vai mostrar no console se vc mandar imprimir no console

Comment: Só abri o console, não dei comando algum, essa screen é do Facebook, não é localhost! Por isso abri a questão.

Comment: Não está claro como fez o teste. Tem certeza que o site do facebook está imprimindo tais dados no console? Se puder descreva melhor, exemplo, esse console é de qual browser? o que é essa url `login.php?lo..` ?  Parece que está fazendo confusão com algo nada a ver.

Comment: Faça o teste ai, usei o FF. Logout, depois abra o console e faça o login, será redirecionado para a página principal e irá aparecer os dados como na imagem que colei. Não imprime no console como se faz com `console.log`, apenas exibe os dados que foram enviados via `POST`.

Comment: Entendido. Isso não é responsabilidade do protocolo https. É um recurso que browsers modernos fornecem nativamente, normalmente em "developer tools > network". São ferramentas de depuração para desenvolvedores. Para não exibir os dados basta interromper a gravação dos logs.

Comment: @PapaCharlie realmente isso acontece, mas isso pq o console analisa o que o navegador está recebendo antes de ser submetido. De outra forma não teríamos como debugar. De fato, isso só se torna um problema se você tiver acesso físico a máquina e se você tiver acesso a esse console no momento em que a pessoa fez algum login e saiu de frente da máquina, pois assim que acontecer o primeiro refresh vc perde essas informações. Por isso não vejo como isso seria um problema. Mas claro, posso estar errado!

Comment: @ThomasLima, mantive a navegação pelo Facebook com o console fechado e quando abri lá estava o `POST login.php?login_attempt=[...]` com os dados do e-mail e senha...

Comment: @PapaCharlie vc navegou no facebook apenas na sua timeline ou entrou em outras perfis? Essas informações estão na aba Rede do console correto? Essa aba só mostra as requisições atuais. Faça um teste, faço o login no facebook, e após logar, de um F5. Veja se as informações ainda estarão lá.